# Accessing individual values from one key (dictionary)

Tags: python, dictionary, f-string

```
people = {"Jenn" : ['renter', 'large room'], 
          "Lana" : ['renter', 'small room'], 
          "Ricky" :['owner', 'large room']
          }
```

Is there a way to access each individual value for a given key via for loop to print the stats of each person? I'm relatively new to Python and I'm having troubles searching for this exact scenario. I'm familiar with f-string formatting.

Expected output for `print()` or `sys.stderr.write()`

```
Jenn is the renter of a large room.
Lana is the renter of a small room.
Rickey is the owner of a large room.
```

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
If you do not know how to iterate through a dict or access its elements, you need to repeat your tutorial on dicts.

Comment: `people[key]` → `list` with two elements, `list[0]` and `list[1]`.

Comment: Noted. I'll be better at asking questions on here.

Answer (score 3):

Use `dict.items()` to loop through `(key, value)` tuples:

```
for key, value in people.items():
    print(f"{key} is the {value[0]} of a {value[1]}")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I merged two dictionaries to obtain my people list and I wasn't sure how to access it prior to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do that:

```
for first, (cat, room) in people.items():
  print(f"{first} is the {cat} of a {room} room")
```

Comment: TIL that this is possible. I wonder why they removed tuple unpacking in function parameters, but not in for loops.